# issues with running parallel step with pipeline plugin

Tags: database, jenkins, groovy, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

```
def stringsToEcho = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
def stepsForParallel = [:]

for (int i = 0; i < stringsToEcho.size(); i++) {
    // Get the actual string here.
    def s = stringsToEcho.get(i)
    def stepName = "echoing ${s}"

    stepsForParallel[stepName] = transformIntoStep(s)
}
parallel stepsForParallel
def transformIntoStep(inputString) {
    return {
        node {
            echo inputString
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen the above code in Jenkins pipeline example page. My requirement is same as above. But here, stringsToEcho has list of default value. But I need to get that list of value from the database. 
Question:
Is it possible to get the list of values from database in that step and assign those values to stringsToEcho??
Kindly help me to resolve the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it should be possible; you can run any steps you want at the start and build a list. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the above code in my Jenkins environment and it is working fine. I have separate java code to retrieve data from my database. now I have to call the java program from this groovy script to get a list of values. and based on the list size , another java method should be called in parallel.

Comment: @Christopher Orr...In Jenkinsfile, 
I have tried to execute a java class by adding the following line..
def b = ‘javac jobs.java’.execute().text 
def c = ‘java jobs’.execute().text
but It is not working..
Can you plz give me some suggestion that how can I call a java method from Jenkinsfile or groovyscript

Comment: I've written an answer to your other question which covers this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42781864/234938