# How to call java function in Jenkinsfile using Pipeline plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using pipeline plugin in jenkins. My `Jenkinsfile` has `numToEcho =1,2,3,4` but I want to call `Test.myNumbers()` to get list of values.

1. How can I call myNumbers() java function in Jenkinsfile?
2. Or do I need to have a separate groovy script file and that file I should place inside java jar which has Test class?

My Jenkinsfile:

```
def numToEcho = [1,2,3,4] 

def stepsForParallel = [:]

for (int i = 0; i < numToEcho.size(); i++) {
def s = numToEcho.get(i)
    def stepName = "echoing ${s}"

    stepsForParallel[stepName] = transformIntoStep(s)
}
parallel stepsForParallel

def transformIntoStep(inputNum) {
    return {
        node {
            echo inputNum
        }
    }
}



import com.sample.pipeline.jenkins
public class Test{

public ArrayList<Integer> myNumbers()    {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(11);
    numbers.add(3);
    return(numbers);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write your logic in a Groovy file, which you can keep in a Git repository, or in a [Pipeline Shared Library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), or elsewhere.

For example, if you had the file `utils.groovy` in your repository:

```java
List<Integer> myNumbers() {
  return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
return this
```

In your `Jenkinsfile`, you could use it like this via the [`load` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#code-load-code-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script):

```java
def utils
node {
  // Check out repository with utils.groovy
  git 'https://github.com/…/my-repo.git'

  // Load definitions from repo
  utils = load 'utils.groovy'
}

// Execute utility method
def numbers = utils.myNumbers()

// Do stuff with `numbers`…
```

---

Alternatively, you can check out your Java code and run it, and capture the output.  Then you could parse that into a list, or whatever data structure you need for later in the pipeline.  For example:

```java
node {
  // Check out and build the Java tool  
  git 'https://github.com/…/some-java-tools.git'
  sh './gradlew assemble'

  // Run the compiled Java tool
  def output = sh script: 'java -jar build/output/my-tool.jar', returnStdout: true

  // Do some parsing in Groovy to turn the output into a list
  def numbers = parseOutput(output)

  // Do stuff with `numbers`…
}
```

Comment: Thanks..this is very helpful..Actually the problem is, I cant write that function in .groovy file, it must be a java file.The actual java function will retreive data(list of values) from titan graph database.. I cant write that function in .groovy file..so how can I call java method from Jenkinsfile or groovyscript..

Comment: In Jenkinsfile:  
node {  
sh ‘java jar titanRead.jar’  
echo inputNum  
}  
 The above part is the parallel part..Now number of this parallel execution will depends on the list size( In the above program list size is 5. so time it will read from titan). That list also, I need to get from titan db using java function.

Comment: Well, you can run anything in Jenkins, so you can run your Java program and parse its output. I've updated the answer to include an example.

Comment: I followed your steps and It is working..Thank you so much..:)